# Visual Studio 2017 Not Supporting .NET 4.6.2

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I'm having trouble creating .NET 4.6.2 projects on my machine (with any version of Visual Studio).

A bit of history. I kept getting errors when I ran the offline installer for .NET 4.6.2 (something about policy - I can make a screenshot available). Then, I ran the Web Installer and it prompted me to *Repair the installation of 4.6.2*. That ran to completion without error. A quick Powershell command confirmed that .NET 4.6.2 is installed on my system:

[image]

However, Visual Studio does not recognise this:

[image]

Does anyone know WTH is going on here?

Comment: Did you install the .NET Framework runtime, or the .NET Framework Developer Pack?

Comment: @yaakov The Developer Pack.